# Send Array of big String (base64 image) to rest services give an error (using tomcat7)

Tags: java, string, rest, base64, tomcat7

I'm tring to send to my rest web service an array of big strings. That strings contain base64 image (each one have size about 4MB).

I'm using tomcat7 and according to tomcat documentation i set maxPostSize to 0 to disable limit post size (i tried also to set 15mb but nothings changes) this is my configuration:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           maxPostSize="0" />
```

This is my params rest interface:

```
    @RequestParam(required = true, value = "idSurvey") Long idSurvey,
@RequestParam(required = false, value = "address") String address,
@RequestParam(required = false, value = "picturesBase64") String[] picturesBase64
```

EDIT:

```
    09:23:46,642 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:959 - Could not complete request
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)


        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            at

 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at it.linksmt.cdb.restful.schede.controller.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:25)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.safeTrim(StringCoding.java:79)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.access$300(StringCoding.java:50)
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:305)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:387)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:956)
        at it.linksmt.cdb.restful.segnalazioni.util.ImageSchedeUtil.decodeImage(ImageSchedeUtil.java:184)
        at it.linksmt.cdb.restful.schede.controller.SendAnswerController.sendAnswer(SendAnswerController.java:96)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at it.linksmt.cdb.restful.schede.controller.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:25)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
```

All works if i send small image.
Any idea?

Comment: WHICH error occurs?
Did you try to submit the request manuelly (curl, for example) to identify a client or server problem?
Did you check the server logfiles?

Comment: @Dany your question now basically boils down to "how to give more heap memory to a Java program?". Google that, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: ok @JBNizet thanks. It means that i need to give more memory to tomcat right?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. Or tune the code so that it consumes less memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to increase heap size, for tomcat you can do

```
export CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms16m -Xmx2G;//change it as per your requriments
```

Comment: yes it is a solution but, please can you help me to tune my code? I mean, which is the better way to store on disk a base64 image? I had out of memory when i decode base64 in byte[]. Thanks